# As (It) Was Explained to You

Tags: pronouns

Is that *it* wrong, or is it just unnecessary but still correct? I have found some questions about that, by which I've been able to understand that it's unnecessary, but I still wonder if it *must* be omitted.

1. As (it) was explained to you yesterday, we will ban you unless you begin following the rules.
2. As (it) has already been said, we cannot let you in.

Comment: Is this construction only used when threatening someone?

Comment: A non-threatening example: "As (was) predicted, the storm arrived at 2 pm." In that example, you *can't* add the "it."

Comment: @alphabet Hmmmm, maybe? I'm not sure *I'd say* "As it was predicted," but I wouldn't call it ungrammatical.

Comment: @alphabet — How do you figure *it* is any less grammatical in your example than in the OP’s?

Comment: @TinfoilHat "As it was predicted" sounds wrong to me. But I may be completely off base.

Answer (score 4):

All 4 versions, with or without "it", are correct and the presence or absence of "it" makes no difference to the meaning. It is unnecessary, but optional. In other words it *may* be omitted. Your choice.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to say that the starting point is awkward: "As has already been said." Unless "A good time was had by all" sounds like fun.

Comment: I disagree that the meaning is the same with or without _it_.  For example, _"You can't bring dogs in here.  As it was explained to you yesterday, we will ban you unless you begin following the rules"_.  This means _"we told you yesterday that you can't bring dogs in here"_.  But if you omit _it_, it means _"we told you yesterday that we will ban you unless you begin following the rules"_.

Comment: (Maybe I should write that as an answer).